# Get indefinite amount of string params from ASP.NET Core route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a basic HttpGet method where people can add an indefinite amount of string params. So basically this means that you can navigate to `api/controller/foo`, `api/controller/foo/bar`, `api/controller/foo/bar/biz`, etc

I tried going at it like below but this doesn't seem to work

```
[HttpGet("{container}/{prefixes}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get(string container, params string[] prefixes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a catch-all template parameter and split the path yourself to solve your problem:

```cs
[HttpGet("{container}/{*prefixPath}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get(string container, string prefixPath)
{
    string[] prefixes = prefixPath?.Split('/');
    ...
}
```

Comment: I thought `*` would still encode the forward slashes, while `**` would not?

Comment: I thought so too when reading the documentation. Alas `**` doesn't work and results in an exception. So it's either a bug in the framework or in the documentation.